# Adding CSS images - Phonegap

Tags: ios, css, xcode, cordova

Im developing a phonegap application using xcode. For the design I have some jquery mobile icons to display for certain buttons. I want to host this jquery mobile stuff on the app rather than having a http link to it (and thus using more bandwidth etc).

On the simulator this works fine and the icons show up, but when put on the phone they dont, i presume i have to tell xcode to put the image files on the phone explicitly? In a .plist or something.

Anyone have any insight?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the phonegap resource should be put in path www.
I never get the thing you described, but i think the error may occur because of your path of image. You may change the folder of jqm and try again.

Comment: Thanks, dont think it is a path error, tried everything, will keep messing though and see if it gets me anywhere!

Comment: Turns out this was an issue with jquery mobile 1.3.0. Fixed the issue and marked it as an issue. Just a dodgy bracket placement in css